# Laravel/Lumen API print array of records

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-blade, lumen

Is it possible to make an API which prints database records like this: `http://localhost:8000/products/?compare=1-2-N...(1,2,N) product id's.` I have succeeded printing only one record. My route:

```
$router->get('products/{id}','ProductController@getProduct');
```

and my controller:

```
public function getProduct($id){

        $tlt_products = DB::table('tlt_products')->find($id);
        $tlt_products_features_id = DB::table('tlt_product_features')->where('product_id', $id)->get()->pluck('feature_id');
        $tlt_features = DB::table('tlt_features')->whereIn('id', $tlt_products_features_id)->get()->groupBy('feature_group');
        $tlt_feature_groups =  DB::table('tlt_features')->groupBy('feature_group')->get()->toArray();

        return response()->json([
            'product' => $tlt_products,
            'product_features' => $tlt_features,
            'feature_groups' => $tlt_feature_groups
        ]);

    }
```

could you please help me printing array of records using route like this:

```
http://localhost:8000/products/?compare=1-2-3...-N
```

Comment: Why you are trying to send this data in URL and making complecated. I think you could send these in POST request and handle it in controller.

Comment: Looks like you should be able to use the php explode function to create an array of ids.  Then you just need to loop thru them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be possible. You can try to pass a pattern through get and parse it to retrieve the information your need, but why don't you use a simple way to do that such as:

```
$router->get('products/{begin}/{end}','ProductController@getProduct');
```

every thing you want it possible just design it well and in your controller, you have

```
public function getProduct($begin,$end){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally managed to solve this issue using  `$tail = $request->tail;`method and adding requested id like this on my form action

```
@php
$tail = basename(request()->path());
$text = (string)$tail; 
@endphp

<form action="/product-compare/{{$text}}-{{ $product['id'] }}" method="post">
```